# Is there a pattern explaining a high number of downvotes on my recent questions?

Tags: discussion, down-votes

I'm aware that questions related to Israel-Palestine are often controversial, and I [asked a few of these](https://politics.stackexchange.com/users/23571/erwan?tab=questions&sort=newest) along the years. But in the past month I asked three questions which collected a particularly high number of downvotes. At the time of writing the counts are:

- [Meaning of "Israel has right to defend itself"](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/82188/meaning-of-israel-has-right-to-defend-itself) 16 downvotes vs 18 upvotes
- [Are international sanctions ever considered against Israel?](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/82675/are-international-sanctions-ever-considered-against-israel) 9 downvotes vs 14 upvotes
- [How did Israel support Hamas precisely?](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/82836/how-did-israel-support-hamas-precisely) 6 downvotes vs 5 upvotes

For the sake of comparison, each of my previous questions on the same topic has around 2 or 3 downvotes at the time of writing.

I don't know if there have been any strong demographic changes among PoliticsSE users, or if my questions have become especially worse? But this looks statistically different.

I'm just reporting this observation here for reference, or in case there is any wrongdoing going on. If someone has a logical explanation, I'd be interested to know about it.

Comment: What I can tell you is that a lot more people put political causes in their user names lately.

Comment: You are not alone - all my questions and answers on this conflict have been heavily downvoted. I attribute this to either information warfare from Israel and / or ordinary Jewish / Israelis members here, inflamed by the war, trying to express their political frustration. In either case, I think we should let it be - due to the war, passion will be high on both side. It should cool down and correct itself later. Those of us getting downvoted should also consider it as an opportunity to evaluate our own (perhaps obsessive) attachment to the issue, and invest our time more productively. :).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The large number of downvotes is an indirect consequence of the October 7th attacks by Hamas on Israel, and the Israeli military response to these attacks.

This has resulted in an intense polarisation of opinion since Oct 7th, and where there are strong polarised opinions, there will be down and up votes from people who reject or share your assumed point of view.

Right now, with tempers running high, you may expect questions about Palestine/Israel to provke downvotes, especially if there is any hint of "taking sides".

Comment: Nevertheless, I hope it is being monitored and studied. Already I've [noticed memes creeping in](https://politics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6655/45056), and not being flagged, when ordinarily such questions would be shut down immediately for *"promoting a cause and not being in good faith"*. I've also pointed out how some questions are getting increasingly closed and reopen multiple times.

Comment: Upvoted, because there is a lot of truth to tempers being short right now.  Nevertheless, 2 out of the 3 questions had serious issues going in:  "meaning of" seems like a bit of pointless nitpicking around terminology (OP admitted some a lack of clarity in response to my comment).  And "support for Hamas" started out as an unanswerable hypothetical (which I DVed before upvoting its final form).  So OP is not entirely innocent in getting DVs for good, if polarizing, Qs, asked in flawed fashion.